# Pandas multi graphing with cufflinks not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I am trying to use cufflinks just like normal plotting on pandas dataframe

```
df:
group people value 
 1     5      100
 2     2      90
 1     10     80
 2     20     40
 1     7      100


import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
cf.go_offline()


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize = (10, 20))
df['value'].iplot(ax = ax1)
df['people'].iplot(ax = ax2)
```

its giving me some strange results, empty graphs, I am not able to use it for secondary axis also

```
ax = df.iplot('value')
df.iplot('people',secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
```

it give me error, "KeyError: True"

They all work fine when I work them with just simple pandas plot. How can I run a secondary axis with pandas and cufflinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the doc here: https://plot.ly/pandas/multiple-axes/#simple-secondary-y-axis-with-secondaryy. secondary_y expects the list of columns to plot on the secondary axis. You passed `True` which is not an column and hence the error.

You want something along the lines of:

```
df.iplot(columns=["people", "value"], secondary_y=['people'])
```